# query with join HibernateTemplate ()

Tags: hibernate

code T the code of class TypeCompetence

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "typeCompetence")
    public Set<Criteres> getCritereses() {
        return this.critereses;
    }
```

the code of class Criteres

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_type_compete")
    public TypeCompetence getTypeCompetence() {
        return this.typeCompetence;
    }
```

the code of class CriteresDAO

```
public List<Criteres> FindidAspetComp(){

        String queryString = "from Criteres c ,TypeCompetence t where c.id_type_compete = t.id_type_compete AND t.id_type_compete = 4 ";
        return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
    }
```

error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: could not resolve property: id_type_compete of: tn.com.ModuleEVL.domaine.Criteres [from tn.com.ModuleEVL.domaine.Criteres c ,tn.com.ModuleEVL.domaine.TypeCompetence t where c.id_type_compete = t.id_type_compete AND t.id_type_compete = 4 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL **never** uses table and column names. It always uses entity names and field/property names. All you need is

```
select c from Criteres c where c.typeCompetence.id = 4
```

Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). And please fix your naming. Entities should not have a plural form, so `Criteres` should be named `Critere`. `getCritereses()` should be named `getCriteres()`. And I can't even understand what `FindidAspetComp()` is supposed to mean. It doesn't respect the Java naming conventions: methods start with a lowercase letter, and are camelCaded..